# Enabling SELinux on RHEL

Tags: linux, security, selinux

I am using RHEL 6.5 and I need to enable SELinux. I have tried following commands, but it does not work:

```
$ setenforce 1
$ echo 1 > /selinux/enforce
```

Note: I also tried editing `/etc/selinux/config`, but there is no such file present.

#### Edit: #1

Output of `sestatus` is as follows:

```
LinuxBox root [scripts] > sestatus
SELinux status:                 disabled
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly search if selinux is installed.

```
rpm -qa | grep selinux, rpm -q policycoreutils, and rpm -qa | grep setroubleshoot
```

If this doesn't show anything then install selinux by,

```
sudo yum install selinux
```

After selinux is installed, configure `SELINUX=permissive` in `/etc/selinux/config`

Then finally restart your computer for selinux to take effect.

Comment: `rpm -qa | grep setroubleshoot` shows nothing, but other two packages are installed there.

Comment: What happens when you re-install selinux?

Answer (score 3):

Given you're using RHEL, SELinux is likely already installed. To confirm:

```
$ rpm -aq | grep -i selinux
selinux-policy-targeted-3.12.1-74.26.fc19.noarch
libselinux-devel-2.1.13-15.fc19.x86_64
libselinux-2.1.13-15.fc19.x86_64
libselinux-utils-2.1.13-15.fc19.x86_64
selinux-policy-3.12.1-74.26.fc19.noarch
libselinux-2.1.13-15.fc19.i686
libselinux-python-2.1.13-15.fc19.x86_64
```

You'll see packages similar to the above. This is from F19, but should apply to your situation as well. You can also confirm using the `setstatus` command:

```
$ sestatus
SELinux status:                 enabled
SELinuxfs mount:                /selinux
Current mode:                   enforcing
Mode from config file:          enforcing
Policy version:                 24
Policy from config file:        targeted
```

There's a warning/note within this document if you're adding SELinux to a system that was initially setup without it.

> If the system was initially installed without SELinux, particularly
>   the selinux-policy package, which was added to the system later, one
>   additional step is necessary to enable SELinux. To make sure SELinux
>   is initialized during system startup, the dracut utility has to be run
>   to put SELinux awareness into the initramfs file system. Failing to do
>   so causes SELinux not to start during system startup.

When dealing with RHEL it's advisable to seek out the excellent manuals that Red Hat maintains for any RHEL release. SELinux is well documented and everything you need to know is covered there.

- [⁠Chapter 5. Working with SELinux](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security-Enhanced_Linux/chap-Security-Enhanced_Linux-Working_with_SELinux.html#sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-Working_with_SELinux-SELinux_Packages)